# Coinbase API - Issue with relationships IDs between Buy and Transaction Data

Tags: coinbase-api

I have been pulling Transaction data from Coinbase and storing the data for over a year.
I also get all data from the Buys and Sells endpoints.
My understanding is that the Buys.transaction.id maps to Transaction.id and vice versa with Transaction.buy.id
I use the Buys.transaction.id to merge data with stored Transaction data.

I recently noticed that the ids sometimes are different and the relationships seem wrong which is causing some issues with merging the Buy data into the Transaction data.
Looking into the data, I see this high-level pattern.

Transaction

```
{
    "id": "A"
    "buy": {
        "id": "B"
    }
}
```

Buy

```
{
    "id": "B",
    "transaction": {
        "id": "C"
    }
}
```

"C" doesn't exist as far as I can tell.
I get a Not Found when trying to access it from the resource path.
I think it should be(and at one time was?) "A".
I don't store the original response so there could be something I am missing that could be highlighted there.

Has anyone else experienced this?

A potential solution is only going off of the Transaction data only buy and ignoring the relationship information on the Buy but I am worried there is something I am missing with how the API works.